# What's a good evaluation method for recommendation systems?

Tags: recommender-system, model-evaluation

I'm using the *100k MovieLense* dataset to build a recommendation system in R, using the `recommenderlab`package.

From what I understood, the `recommenderlab` package kind of *forces* the user to use the following evaluation technique.

- Split the dataset into training and test sets.
- Split the test set into known and unknown, base in the `given` argument

This is what's done when I run the following:

```
library(recommenderlab)
data(MovieLense)
MovieLense <- binarize(MovieLense, minRating=4)
MovieLense <- MovieLense[rowSums(MovieLense) > 4,]

eva <- evaluationScheme(
  data = MovieLense,
  method = "split",
  train = 0.75, 
  given = 3 
)
```

So I my folowing work is:

- Train the recommender using the traing set
- Predict rating for users in the test set using the *known* data
- Evaluate prediction accuracy in the *unknown* test set data

This is performed using:

```
rec <- Recommender(getData(eva, "train"), method = "IBCF")
pred <- predict(rec, getData(eva, "known"), type = "topN", n = 5)
error <- calcPredictionAccuracy(pred, getData(eva, "unknown"), given = 3)
```

After all this, my question is:

- Is this a good evaluation technique?

I'm not confortable in using always only 3 given items to predict users ratings, because I think the algorithm could have a better performance if I used more ratings in prediction.

But, I know that if I use more "given" items, my precision will be smaller because there will be less relevant items too.

So, how do I choose the best number of items?

If this is a wrong way the evaluate my system:

- What's the best way to measure my algorithm performance?